# discord.js Permission Module keeps printing undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created a permission module for my bot and can't see why it isn't working. All I get is undefined printed in the console.

Command:

```js
const guild = PermissionManager.fetchGuild(message.guild.id);
const ClientPermissions = await PermissionManager.fetchPerms(client, message, 4);
console.log(ClientPermissions);
if (ClientPermissions == false) {
  PermissionManager.invalidPerms(message, 4);
} else {
  // execute command 
}
```

Permission Module:
https://pastebin.com/qrBdqDuP

Example JSON data from `GuildSettings.findOne()`:

```json
{
  "created": 1622683302442,
  "prefix": "!",
  "modules": {
    "logs": {
      "ModLogs": [],
      "GeneralLogs": []
    },
    "staff": {
      "ModRole": "Employee",
      "ManagerRole": "System Admin"
    }, 
    "other": { 
      "ProgressBarColor": "#2EA5FF"
    }, 
    "welcome": { 
      "enabled": true,
      "channel": "825896631152017458", 
      "message": "Welcome to RAMAPGE Interactive {user.ping}, Enjoy your stay here. Total Users: {guild.totalUser}" 
    }, 
    "goodbye": { 
      "enabled": false, 
      "channel": null, 
      "message": null 
    } 
  }, 
  "_id": "60b82eae964d1a6b8ce43750", 
  "guildID": "824836684889587782", 
  "__v": 0 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the rest of the code? What is PermissionManager? What is fetchPerms? We need more information to be able to help.

Comment: .fetchPerms is PermissionManager snippet of code is whats ran to see if they have correct permissions to use the command.

Comment: Can you post the full code for the PermissionManager? It is hard to know why it is returning undefined from that snippet

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qrBdqDuP

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchPerms` function does not return anything currently. Instead, you should return a `Promise` like so:

```js
// taken from https://pastebin.com/qrBdqDuP (from author comments)
module.exports.fetchPerms = function(de, message, level) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const LevelNeed = ConvertLevelToRank(level);
        GuildSettings.findOne({
            guildID: message.guild.id
        }, (err, guild) => {
            switch(level) {
                case 1:
                    resolve(message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === guild.modules.staff.ModRole || role.name === guild.modules.staff.ManagerRole || role.id === guild.modules.staff.ModRole || role.id === guild.modules.staff.ManagerRole || message.author.id == "295744013406044162" || message.author.id == message.guild.owner));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    resolve(message.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === guild.modules.staff.ManagerRole || role.id === guild.modules.staff.ManagerRole || message.author.id == "295744013406044162" || message.author.id == message.guild.owner));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    resolve(message.author.id == "295744013406044162" || message.author.id == message.guild.owner);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    resolve(message.author.id == "2957440134060441622");
                    break;
                default:
                    resolve(true);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: unreleated code checks guild settings for the guild permission roles and returns accordingly if they got permission to use the command or not. Still doesn't work

Comment: Is it still returning undefined when it shouldn't?

Comment: it returns whole guild settings json when it should be returning true or false if they have permissions or not.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it returns true or false

Comment: So how do I return data from guildsettings to fetchPerms to return

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is it always returning the guild json (or always true)? If so, can you update your question to include the code for `GuildSettings.findOne` and an example of what your JSON data looks like?

Comment: {
  created: 1622683302442,
  prefix: '!',
  modules: {
    logs: { ModLogs: [Object], GeneralLogs: [Object] },
    staff: { ModRole: 'Employee', ManagerRole: 'System Admin' },
    other: { ProgressBarColor: '#2EA5FF' },
    welcome: {
      enabled: true,
      channel: '825896631152017458',
      message: 'Welcome to RAMAPGE Interactive {user.ping}, Enjoy your stay here. Total Users: {guild.totalUser}'
    },
    goodbye: { enabled: false, channel: null, message: null }
  },
  _id: 60b82eae964d1a6b8ce43750,
  guildID: '824836684889587782',
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Could you also edit your post to include the code for the `GuildSettings.findOne()` method. I don't want to answer just yet, as I don't know the purpose of the function being passed into `GuildSettings.findOne` yet.

Comment: It's a function of mongoose Database.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

Comment: I have updated my answer using the current information. Hopefully, it works for you!